# AppDomain.CurrentDomain.RelativeSearchPath is null in Unit Test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, relative-path

I have email templates (and emailer) in separate class library project. I am getting path to views (copy to ouput directory = true) like this:

```
var basePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.RelativeSearchPath;
var path = Path.Combine(basePath, "Views", viewname + ".cshtml");
```

When I try to run this code in unit test project basePath is null.But it shouldn't be null!!

Who can explain me -

1. why basepath is null?
2. how to fix it?

Comment: Have you set it via `AppDomainSetup.PrivateBinPath`?

Comment: no, I havent used this property

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.relativesearchpath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Private assemblies are deployed in the same directory structure as the
>   application. If the path specified by the RelativeSearchPath property
>   is not under AppDomainSetup.ApplicationBase, it is ignored.
>
> This property returns the value set using
>   AppDomainSetup.PrivateBinPath.

You should set [AppDomainSetup.PrivateBinPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomainsetup.privatebinpath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) first.